# How can a grid mesh be unwrapped to overlayed quads?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a grid mesh on the floor and want to UV map it to an image of 2x2 tiles.
I remember that there was an option which allows it to map all quads over another, but I no longer know what the name of the menu items was.

[image]

Between the tiles are joints (in case this makes a difference), detail view:

[image]

Comment: There are several addons for uv's. Maybe you haven't enabled it or haven't installed it into your current blender? Try the scripts folder next to the user config for older versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with an unwrapped grid (without the joints), press <kbd>U</kbd> in *Edit Mode* to bring up the unwrap popup and chose *Reset*:

[image]

After scaling down all UVs to the size of a single tile they can be distributed by repeated *Random Deselect* from the *Select Menu* in *Edit Mode*

[image]